# How to create Thick Semi Transparent plastic?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, photorealism, shader-nodes

I would like to create  semi transparent plastic material in cycles like this reference picture.

[image]

This is my current node setup.

[image]

And this is the result i am getting. Ignore the background.

[image]

and when i try to render it renders very neat and clean which i don't want because real world objects are not very neat.

Any help or suggestion.Thanks

Thanks for your reply moonboots. I have tried your method but i am getting different results.
[image]

[image]

Am i doing something wrong

when i try to change the color ramp it becomes very shiny and reflective and it doesn't show any transparency.

[image]

[image]

sorry for the late reply

It's Still not working.
[image]

Comment: maybe try to lighten up a bit the colors of the top ColorRamp?

Answer (score 4):

You could try that:

[image]

It's just a mix between a *Transparent* and a *Glossy*, with a *Layer Weight* as factor. Give it a bit of *Noise* if you don't want your material to be to homogeneous:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Material is transparent and refractive, not translucent.
You can just use a dark glass shader (since you have kind of a fresnel setup, just use the Principled BSDF Shader with transmission set to 1).
Also the roughness in your reference is very low, a .02 would do (keeps the sharp reflections and refractions).